# Color sections of a path in d3.js with different colors based on ordinal values

Tags: d3.js

For a line chart, I am trying to color different sections of a single path based on the values of a specific data column that contains ordinal data ("W" and "L"), in this case the "result" column.

I have tried using a linearGradient:

```
svg.append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", gradient.id)
      .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("y1", margin.top)
      .attr("x2", 0)
      .attr("y2", height - margin.bottom)
    .selectAll("stop")
      .data([
        {offset: "W", color: "red"},
        {offset: "L", color: "gray"}
      ])
    .join("stop")
      .attr("offset", d => d.offset)
      .attr("stop-color", d => d.color);

svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("stroke", gradient)
```

In another attempt, I have applied a colorScale to the result column.

```
svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("stroke", function(d) {
        return colorScale(d.result)
      });
```

Unfortunately, none of these attempts worked. Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks!